# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException showing up in my JFrame

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, exception, jframe

I'm a pretty new programmer, and I'm currently creating a program that will be used as a database for a school club. I currently the options on my first JFrame to do the following:

- Create a new student profile (Second JFrame Form)
- List the students and their info (Third JFrame Form)
- Create a new activity profile (Fourth JFrame Form)
- List the activities and their info (Fifth JFrame Form)

My first, second, third and fifth frames work fine when compiled. However, I have a problem compiling my Fourth `JFrame` form.This form is meant to add a new activity, and has 3 text fields; one for the activity name, one for the activity date, and one for the activity attendance. There is also a button that says `"Add activity"` that will add the new activity to an Activity array. This button also closes the fourth `JFrame` and sets the First `JFRame` to true.

When I press the `"Add activity"` button, it gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at FourthForm.addActivityButtonActionPerformed(FourthForm.java:157)
at FourthForm.access$600(FourthForm.java:11)
at FourthForm$7.actionPerformed(FourthForm.java:79)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Here is my code for the fourth `JFrame`:

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Username
 */
public class FourthForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private FirstForm first;

    /**
     * Creates new form FourthForm
     */
    public FourthForm() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        activityNameTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        activityDateTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        activityAttendanceTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        addActivityButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(800, 600));
        setResizable(false);

        activityNameTextField.setText("Enter activity name here");
        activityNameTextField.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                activityNameTextFieldMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        activityNameTextField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                activityNameTextFieldActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        activityDateTextField.setText("Enter date of activity here");
        activityDateTextField.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                activityDateTextFieldMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        activityDateTextField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                activityDateTextFieldActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        activityAttendanceTextField.setText("Enter activity attendance here");
        activityAttendanceTextField.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                activityAttendanceTextFieldMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        activityAttendanceTextField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                activityAttendanceTextFieldActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        addActivityButton.setText("Add activity");
        addActivityButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                addActivityButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(77, 77, 77)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(activityNameTextField)
                        .addComponent(activityDateTextField)
                        .addComponent(activityAttendanceTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 240, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addComponent(addActivityButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 120, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(483, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(71, 71, 71)
                .addComponent(activityNameTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(43, 43, 43)
                .addComponent(activityDateTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(37, 37, 37)
                .addComponent(activityAttendanceTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(54, 54, 54)
                .addComponent(addActivityButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 62, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(273, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void activityNameTextFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:


    }                                                     

    private void activityDateTextFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:

    }                                                     

    private void activityAttendanceTextFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:

    }                                                           

    private void activityNameTextFieldMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        activityNameTextField.setText("");
    }                                                  

    private void activityDateTextFieldMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        activityDateTextField.setText("");
    }                                                  

    private void activityAttendanceTextFieldMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        activityAttendanceTextField.setText("");
    }                                                        

    private void addActivityButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String d = activityNameTextField.getText();
        String e = activityDateTextField.getText();
        String f = activityAttendanceTextField.getText();

        int attendance = Integer.parseInt(f);

        Activity a = new Activity(d, e, attendance);

        first.addActivity(a);
        this.setVisible(false);
        first.setVisible(true);


    }                                                 

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
    */

    public void createActivity(FirstForm f)
    {
        activityNameTextField.setText(" ");
        activityDateTextField.setText(" ");
        activityAttendanceTextField.setText(" ");


        this.setVisible(true);
        first = f;

    }
//    public static void main(String args[]) {
//        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
//        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
//        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
//         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
//         */
//        try {
//            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
//                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
//                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
//                    break;
//                }
//            }
//        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
//            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FourthForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
//        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
//            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FourthForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
//        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
//            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FourthForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
//        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
//            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FourthForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
//        }
//        //</editor-fold>
//
//        /* Create and display the form */
//        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
//            public void run() {7
//              
//            }
//        });
//    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextField activityAttendanceTextField;
    private javax.swing.JTextField activityDateTextField;
    private javax.swing.JTextField activityNameTextField;
    private javax.swing.JButton addActivityButton;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

I would like to note that the code used in this frame follows the same structure as the one in my second `jFrame`, in which I add students instead of activities.

If I could get some insight on this, I'd appreciate it! If you need the code for any of my other `JFrames`, just ask.

Comment: The only assignment to `first` happens in `createActivity(…)`, but no-one is invoking that method. So `first` is still `null` when you try to access it in `addActivityButtonActionPerformed`.

Comment: @Holger how do I invoke the method?

Comment: It's your program. You should already have had an idea of when and how to invoke that method when you created it.